# Get an instance of View Model created in OnStartup in the Bootstrapper

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am still fairly new to WPF and Caliburn, however, given that I have the following in my bootstrapper class:

```
    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRootViewFor<MainWindowViewModel>();
    }
```

As I understand (or don't) the DisplayRootViewFor creates an instance of View and ViewModel classes, binds them and displays them. So what I would like is to be able to get that instance of the ViewModel class. It may be that I am not really understanding MVVM principles in general but essentially, in my View I would like to be able to say something simple like:

```
    MainWindowViewModel vm = ?;
    vm.Property = "Hi this is a test";
```

So what would go in the '?' or is this just frowned upon in general?

EDIT: 
As mentioned in the below answer with comments, I am looking to work with Avalon Dock and this is famously bad at being accessible from the MVVM portion. Really I am just looking for a way to find the correct instance of the ViewModel that is created when calling the OnStartup. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caliburn Micro works a bit different from most MVVM frameworks, in that is it model-first, i.e, the name of the model (e.g. `MainWindowViewModel`) determines what view is created (`MainWindowView` in this case), and Caliburn Micro takes care of the creation and bindings wiring for the pair. It does this using a number of standard (but overridable) conventions.

The idea behind having a View Model - View pair is that the View binds to and displays the content and state of the View Model, and that it triggers commands in the View Model, when the user manipulates elements in the view (e.g. presses a button). The View Model is responsible for reacting to these commands, and updating it's state or content accordingly. When it has done so, the view will reflect the new state or content.

In general, and this may be confusing if you are used to other MVVM frameworks, Caliburn Micro requires **0** lines of "code behind" for your View class, as all binding can generally be done in the XAML only.

To illustrate with a very basic example of a screen that allows selecting a salutation for the user from a list of available salutations, displays a preview for the selected user salutation, and allows saving it.

```
public class UserSalutationViewModel : Screen
{
    private readonly string _userName;
    private readonly IDataService _dataService;
    private string _selectedSalutation;

    public UserSalutationViewModel(string userName, IDataService dataService)
    {   
        _userName = userName;
        _dataService = dataService;
        Salutions = new BindableCollection<string>(_dataService.GetAvailableSalutations());
        _selectedSalutation = _dataService.GetUserSalutation(_userName);
    }

    // List with selectable salutations. Bound in the View to a ListBox element.
    public BindableCollection<string> Salutions { get; private set;}

    // Caliburn Micro will automatically bind this to the selected item in the ListBox.
    public string SelectedSalutation 
    {
        get { return _selectedSalutation; }
        set
        {
            _selectedSaluation = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedSalutation);
            // Notify the view to refresh with the new user salutation value
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => UserSaluation);
        }
    }

    // This returns a model constructed value. Bound to a Label element in the View
    public string UserSalutation
    {
        get { return _selectedSaluation + " " + _userName; }
    }

    // Saves the selected salutation. Bound to a Button in the View
    public void Save()
    {
        _dataService.SaveUserSalutation(_userName, _selectedSalutation);
    }
}
```

Then the `UserSalutationView` XAML could be really simple as well, laying out only the elements in the view.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.UserSalutationView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" x:Name="UserSalutation"/>  
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Salutions"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" x:Name="Save" Content="Save user salutation"/>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

The `x:Name` parts in the XAML are used in the wireup of View with ViewModel by Caliburn.

Comment: That's cool and kind of what I'm using Caliburn. However, things like Avalon Dock are famously bad at providing MVVM support, so adding dynamic items to Avalon Dock has to be done in the code behind for the view. How do I subscribe to an event in the ViewModel from the View if I don't have the instance of the ViewModel class that I create on startup? Hence the original question. thanks for your detailed answer though.

Comment: Than it would have been helpful if you had been more specific in your question about what it was that you were trying to achieve, instead of asking if manipulating the view model through code behind is frowned upon (as it is, when generally better approaches are available. I believe a solution for the Avalon Dock issue you mentioned can be found here: http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/430994 and have a look at https://github.com/tgjones/gemini/

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer even though it isn't really what I am using as I think this is probably better for future devs to aspire to than the fudge that I wrote to get it working. Thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome, no hard feelings. It would not have existed had your question been formulated a bit more precisely ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To directly access a Caliburn Micro View Model from the code behind in your View, you can access its `DataContext` property and cast it to the view model type. Like so (in `UserSalutationView.xaml.cs`):

```
// Get my UserSalutationViewModel
var viewModelInstance = DataContext as UserSalutationViewModel;
```

Comment: I tried this. I need access in the view constructor. My ViewModel is setup properly then, but when debugging this the DataContext is null. Sh doe you know when the datacontext is set in Caliburn.Micro?  What would be a place to obtain these data, I need it before rendering the view.